# Data for Json in php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I cant get my values from the database to go into the jquery tags plugin, any help would be great:

PHP:

```
case 'get_tags':
        $id         = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
        $query      = "SELECT description FROM `tags` WHERE page_id = '?';";
        $query_p    = $db->prep_query($query,array($id));
        $results    = $db->queryMakearray($query_p);

        $tags = array_values($results);
        $response   = json_encode($results);
break;
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var _id = parseInt($.url_param('id'), 10);
    var _tag_items = $.get('inc/ajax.php?type=get_tags&id='+_id);
    $('#tags')
        .textext({
        plugins : 'tags',
        tagsItems: _tag_items
    });
});
```

Response:

```
"[{\"description\":\"test\"},{\"description\":\"test2\"},{\"description\":\"test3\"}]"
```

I need it to look like this:

```
["test","test2","test3"]
```

***Edit***

PHP:

```
$id         = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
        $query      = "SELECT description FROM `tags` WHERE page_id = '?';";
        $query_p    = $db->prep_query($query,array($id));
        $results    = $db->query2array($query_p);

        $tags   = array_values($results);
        $response = sanitize_output($tags);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could solve it in php by removing the key.

```
    foreach($results => $value);
    {
        $results[] = $value['description'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your JSON (_tag_items) to array. You could do like this :

```
var finalArray = [];
for(var i in _tag_items) {
    if(_tag_items.hasOwnProperty(i) && !isNaN(+i)) {
        finalArray[+i] = _tag_items[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: _tag_items[i] will result in {"description":"test"}, {"description":"test2"}, {"description":"test3"}

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var _id = parseInt($.url_param('id'), 10);
    var _tag_items = $.get('inc/ajax.php?type=get_tags&id='+_id);
    var _newTag = [];
    for(var i=0; i<_tag_items.length; i++)
    {
        _newTag.push(_tag_items[i].description);
    }
    $('#tags')
        .textext({
        plugins : 'tags',
        tagsItems: _newTag
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mRp4h/1/)

Comment: Thanks I tweaked my php as I realised I wasnt getting correct data. but all I am gettin is ["Array","Array","Array","Array","Array"].
I will update my code above.